# Create sequence if not exist in DuckDB

Tags: sql, duckdb

It seems like DuckDB does not support this:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_personid START 1 IF NOT EXIST;
```

Postres has this feature https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html

What would be the best workaround if DuckDB does not support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are using the if not exists correctly.

It should be:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS seq_personid START 1;
```

Comment: Right! Thank you.

So, my question is not correct. Should I close it? How does it work in stackoverflow? :)